# How to print the content of <div> tag as same it is?

Tags: html

I want to print the content of  tag. All the previous question on portal shows the answer but in that the card shape in print tab is distorted.I want the exact same print of ID card. I want the output as the div content is written.[I want to print the ID card with the black borders.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btUHs.png) the  tag has a css file include. 
Please see the picture

Comment: By print, do you mean you want to print a physical copy and when doing so it gets distorted?

Comment: yes when i used javascript or jquery it opens a new tab with print window but all the layout for id gets changed. Please see the picture i inluded. it has a id card i want to print it not the whole page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into CSS media queries.

```
@media print{

}
```

Can be used to apply specific CSS rules to the document when outputted to the printer. I'm guessing your issue is that you are trying to print the entire page and not just the card, causing scale-based distortion.

EDIT:

Here's a nice thorough introduction to print styles: http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial

EDIT:

Here's a more concrete answer to your question:

```
@media print{
  *{
    display: none;
  }
  html, body, #card{
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

The * rule is a wildcard to hide everything -- you may need to customize this if your #card is wrapped in anything (you don't want to hide those -- you'll just want to remove any styles on them, such as background color, margins, or padding).

The next rule makes sure html, body, and #card are shown and have no margins applied to them -- this is to ensure that #card is positioned flush with the top-left of the page.

I've also thrown a max-width: 100% and height: auto on those elements to ensure #card can't be larger than the page.

Comment: It could also be that your margins/padding are throwing the content you wish to print off the page causing two pages to be printed.

Comment: thank you for that but i am trying to just print the card only as you can see in the picture i included in the post.

Comment: Exactly -- use the @media print directive to apply `display: none;` to everything except the card.

Comment: Actually @jonny i am new to css and web development could you elaborate your answer with actual code . My <div> tag id is "card" . If you could do this it will be a great help.

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer to show how I'd approach a solution to your problem.

Comment: and how to invoke print function

Comment: You can invoke the print function from a link as such: `<a href="javascript:window.print()">Print</a>`

Comment: all is working fine but when i use print  the card is not showing if i remove * from the code it work but gets the all html component .so please help @JonnyAsmar